Modal logic: condition corresponding to $\Diamond \Box (A \Rightarrow B)\Rightarrow (\Diamond \Box A \Rightarrow \Diamond \Box B)$?
In normal modal logic, what would be the condition on the accessibility relation corresponding to the following axiom (the analogue of the distribution axiom for $\Diamond \Box$ instead of $\Box$):
$\Diamond \Box (A \Rightarrow B)\Rightarrow (\Diamond \Box A \Rightarrow \Diamond \Box B)$?
I know that this schema is derivable in S5 and S4.2, but not in S4; what I'm trying to do is to find out is what is possibly the weakest logic that validates it. I did some digging, but I haven't found any useful procedure for coming up with semantic analogues (first- or second-order) to axioms which cannot be put in the general form required by Lemmon-Scott theorem. I'd deeply appreciate any help with this question, even just pointing the relevant literature that might be of help, as I am not a mathematician but philosopher myself.

I can’t help with the specific frame condition, but the formula is valid in frames that are both transitive and symmetric.

If I have not made any mistakes (I invite you to check thouroughly, correspondence proofs can often have mysterious holes), I think this axiom defines some strange variant of directedness: if $xRy$ and $xRz$ then there is some $w$ such that $xRw$ and whenever $wRk$ then $yRk$ and $zRk$. Call this a super-directed frame, and a $w$ in these conditions a "witness" for super-directedness.
Let me provide a correspondence proof. This assumes familiarity with Kripke semantics, but I hope that will not be a problem. First, assume that $(X,R)$ is a super-directed frame. Suppose that $x\Vdash \Diamond \Box (a\rightarrow b)$ and $x\Vdash \Diamond \Box a$. Let $y$ and $z$ respectively be witnesses. Since $xRy$ and $xRz$, by super-directedness, there is some $w$ such that $xRw$ in the right conditions. Now if $wRk$ then because $yRk$, $k\Vdash a$; and because $zRk$, $k\Vdash a\rightarrow b$, so $k\Vdash b$. So $w\Vdash \Box b$, as desired.
Now assume that $(X,R)$ is not super-directed. Let $xRy$ and $xRz$ with no $w$ witnessing super-directedness. Let $V$ be a valuation such that $V(a)=\{k : yRk\}$ and $V(b)=\{k : yRk \wedge zRk\}$. Then $y\Vdash \Box a$ and note that $z\Vdash \Box (a\rightarrow b)$: if $zRm$, and $m\Vdash a$, then by definition, $yRm$, so $m\in V(b)$, i.e., $m\Vdash b$. Now assume that $x\Vdash \Diamond \Box b$. Then by definition, $xRw$, and $w\Vdash \Box b$. But then whenever $wRk$, then $yRk$ and $zRk$ -- i.e., $w$ is a super-directed witness.
Note that if you assume transitivity, then super-directedness coincides with directedness: if $xRy$ and $xRz$, any successor of $y$ and $z$, say $w$, will be a super-directed witness in the above sense.
Some further notes: the principle you are considering is indeed the Kripke axiom for the composed modality $\Diamond \Box$. This is equivalent to adding the two normality conditions for the  I know that in epistemic logic this modality is sometimes considered, since it can be useful to axiomatise forms of belief. I have searched in the literature for whether anything is known about adding these normality rules for composed modalities, but have not found anything. I would be interested to know what is your motivation for studying this principle!

Thanks! I am now away from the computer and I will check the proof more thoroughly when I have the opportunity, but it seems persuasive. Brief motivation: you’re right about epistemic logic and defining belief within it; as most systems (Stalnaker’s and Lenzen’s) use S4.2 for knowledge to do it (and define a KD45 belief), I was wondering what is in fact the weakest epistemic logic that encode some belief operator as $\Diamond \Box$. D is obviously equivalent to .2 on this reading, which corresponds to convergence, and necessitation is secured by reflexivity, but I was troubled by K.

Now when I’m looking at it, it seems to me that if $R$ is reflexive, then every „super-directed” frame would be also convergent, which would be quite cool :)

I agree, reflexivity also implies that "super-directed" equals convergence, so this truly is a condition that lives away from the "usual" frame conditions. Also some things I realized in the mean time, in case you are interested in metalogical properties: let SD be the system K+"Axiom above". By some heavy duty theorems (namely the Fine-Van Benthem theorem), if this logic is complete, it must be canonical. So the only way to prove this logic complete will be through a canonical model argument. I have briefly sketched one, and it seems to me that this should in fact be the case.

Not the sought answer precisely, but an answer, anyway, hoping to be of some help:
In what follows, I shall employ the derived rule transitivity of implication (TI) of propositional calculus:
$$p\rightarrow q, q\rightarrow r\vdash p\rightarrow r$$
Also, for my argument, my reference will be the section 4 of An Introduction to Modal Logic by E. J. Lemmon (in collaboration with D. Scott, edited by K. Segerberg, 1977).
So, note that
$$\Box(p\rightarrow q)\rightarrow(\Diamond p\rightarrow\Diamond q)$$
which can be straightforwardly derived from axiom K, the definition $\Box\phi\leftrightarrow\neg\Diamond\neg\phi$, and propositional calculus,  without calling in axiom D.
By taking $p$ and $q$ as $\Box A$ and $\Box B$, respectively, we can write
(1) $\Box(\Box A\rightarrow\Box B)\rightarrow(\Diamond\Box A\rightarrow\Diamond\Box B)$
By axiom K, we have
(2) $\Box\Box(A\rightarrow B)\rightarrow\Box(\Box A\rightarrow\Box B)$
From (1) and (2), by TI
(3) $\Box\Box(A\rightarrow B)\rightarrow(\Diamond\Box A\rightarrow\Diamond\Box B)$
By axiom B
(4) $\Diamond\Box\Box(A\rightarrow B)\rightarrow\Box(A\rightarrow B)$
By axiom 4
(5) $\Box(A\rightarrow B)\rightarrow\Box\Box(A\rightarrow B)$
From (4) and (5), by TI
(6) $\Diamond\Box(A\rightarrow B)\rightarrow\Box\Box(A\rightarrow B)$
From (3) and (6), by TI
(7) $\Diamond\Box(A\rightarrow B)\rightarrow(\Diamond\Box A\rightarrow\Diamond\Box B)$
Therefore, we need the symmetric relation by B and transitive relation by 4. Since a symmetric relation is also euclidean, when it is transitive, we may also say that the formula holds on euclidean frames.

Thanks, that is helpful! If I understand correctly, the argument proves that the axiom is derivable in KB4(=KB5) and suggests that it is derivable in K5 - which is in fact the case, as I checked in umsu proof generator. Though, as the axiom is derivable in S4.2, being euclidean in not necessary, but it certainly is sufficient.

The condition found by the software system SQEMA is
$$\forall y_{1}\forall y_{2}(((xRy_{1})\land  (xRy_ {2}))\rightarrow\exists z_{1}((xRz_{1})\land\forall z_{2}((z_{1}Rz_{2})\rightarrow ((y_{1}Rz_{2})\land (y_{2}Rz_{2})))))$$
which is indeed some form of directedness. It also provides a proof by resolution.

Great! That confirms the condition given above by Rodrigo - I haven't heard about SQEMA before, thank you very much for the reference!
